# How to align check boxes in frame Layout

Tags: android

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my main xml file but my all check boxes are collapsing. i want it vertically.
please suggest me.

Comment: Take LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout..

Comment: @Amit, check my answer below and let me know it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `FrameLayout` with `LinearLayout`. From the docs:

`FrameLayout` is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, `FrameLayout` should be used to hold a **single** child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a `FrameLayout` and control their position within the `FrameLayout` by assigning gravity to each child, using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below. No need to use framelayout, you can directly implement this with LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="click" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="click" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="click" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="click" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout inside that   tablelayout an then use tablerowlayout. and put your checkboxes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/jimmy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="one" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/diana"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="two" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/dina"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="three" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/jack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="four" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want 1 help, that how to post question in stackoverflow, whenever i try to post, it show please enter correct format, please add some text to expalin problem, i done will all, but still showing that error, please help.

Comment: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx